# Essential packages for web development workflow on Sublime Text 3

Tags: web-development, text-editor, workflow

### Any good suggestion from your experience?

1. *Handy packages on ST3 improve efficiency dramatically and how to choose them is NOT really a question asking for opinions, but a `Problem` to be solved!*
2. *My installed packages are listed as appendix, it will be updated frequently and contributors will be @ here:*

### Appendix:

*Package Control should be a must for everyone!* [Explore Packages](https://sublime.wbond.net/browse)

---

*{ fast typing }*

> - **Emmet**
>     *- "Emmet (ex-Zen Coding) for Sublime Text."*
> - **Doc​Blockr**
>     *- "Simplifies writing DocBlock comments in Javascript, PHP, CoffeeScript, Actionscript, C & C++."*
> - **Emmet Css Snippets**
>     *- "Emmet CSS completions for Sublime Text."*
> - **Bootstrap 3 Snippets**
>     *- "Twitter Bootstrap 3 Snippets Plugin for Sublime Text."*
> - **Better Completion**
>     *- "Better auto-completion for Sublime Text."*
> - **All Autocomplete**
>     *- "Extend Sublime text autocompletion to find matches in all open files of the current window."*
> - **Auto​File​Name**
>     *- "Sublime Text plugin that autocompletes filenames."*
> - **j​Query**
>     *- "Sublime Text package bundle for jQuery."*

---

*{ formatting }*

> - **Js​Format**
>     *- "Javascript formatting for Sublime Text."*
> - **HTMLBeautify**
>     *- "A plugin for Sublime Text that formats (indents) HTML source code. It makes code easier for humans to read."*

---

*{ utility }*

> - **SideBarEnhancements**
>     *- "Enhancements to Sublime Text sidebar, Files and folders."*
> - **View In Browser**
>     *- "Open the contents of your current view/tab in a web browser."*

---

*{ system }*

> - **Plain​Tasks**
>     *- "An opinionated todo-list plugin for Sublime Text."*
> - **Theme - Soda**
>     *- "Dark and light custom UI themes for Sublime Text."*

Comment: You've already covered the ground, what more you need?

Comment: @Mr.Alien I want the space :) Seriously, as almost all those I have included are from TOP 100 ST3 packages, so I wonder if others can find other not so famous but still incredible ones.

Comment: For those who think it is off-topic, I would say third-party packages/plug-ins are indeed softwares. Come on, even Java Libraries are considered to be softwares, it is 21st century, softwares are not necessarily to be independent and self-contained. Another thing that is worth mentioning: where else can I post this question?!

Comment: Actually its not off topic because you want some similar recommendations to the plugins, but we entertain questions where the OP has issues and he is finding a new software to use, also I personally feel that question is bit broad, so try asking them like "Plugin to auto complete HTML tags", "Plugin to view the pages directly in different browser from Sublime Text" and so on :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Well, if I want to post a wiki-like question concerning web development, is there a StackExchange sub-community suitable for this?

Comment: Yes I knew it that you were looking for a canonical post but unfortunately they are now considered as too broad, offtopic or primarily opinion based, they were allowed before few years but now they aren't allowed any more...

Comment: @Mr.Alien whoops, thank you for your kindly explanation...

Comment: You welcome :) and look at any of the canonical question on Stackoverflow, they will be closed already...